# how to space two sentences if you are multiplying same sentence

Tags: spacing

I want to multiply a name like a = "name" but space them between 
like a*3 = 'namenamename'
I want it in this way = 'name name name', but i don't want to add space to the end of a

Comment: In what language? Python, SQL, Java, etc...

Comment: Depends on the language, but you probably want to have an `if` statement in your loop that checks the iterator to see if it's the final invocation, and only adds the space if it's not.